# How to properlly allocate memory for structures in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I dont know how to allocate memory for a struct in my C program without it segmentation faulting.

```
typedef struct Player{
      char *name,  *surname;
      int xp;
} Player;

typedef struct Team{
      char *name;
      Player *player;
} Team;

typedef struct List
{
    Team *team;
    struct List *next;
} List_Node;
```

I need to make a list of teams with an array of players but for my program to not Segfault I need to malloc every member of every structure. Then I have to free every member of every structure. It is a resonably big project and I get heap corruption errors and I dont know if I initialize my structures correctly.

With the pointer initialized in main.

```
List_Node *list_node = (List_Node*)malloc(sizeof(List_node));
```

And the function

```
void create_list_Node(List_Node *temp)
{
    temp->team = malloc....
    temp->team->name = malloc....
    temp->team->player = malloc....
    temp->team->player->name = malloc....
    temp->team->player->surname = malloc....
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

Called with the node as a parameter.

Comment: Please show how you call your function.

Comment: There's no way for us to help you debug this without all the relevant code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use a memory checker. For Linux there is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce "many pieces of memory scattered all over the place" (and the hassle of keeping track of where all the little pieces are allocated/freed) you can allocate a single piece of memory for multiple things (e.g. a structure plus a string). For example:

```
typedef struct Player{
      char *name,  *surname;
      int xp;
} Player;

typedef struct Team{
      struct Team *next;
      char *name;
      Player *player;
} Team;

Player *createPlayer(char *name, char *surname, int xp) {
    Player *newPlayer;
    int len1, len2;

    len1 = strlen(name);
    len2 = strlen(surname);
    newPlayer = malloc(sizeof(Player) + len1+1 + len2+1);
    if(newPlayer != NULL) {
        newPlayer->next = NULL;
        newPlayer->name = (char *)newPlayer + sizeof(Player);
        memcpy(newPlayer->name, name, len1+1);
        newPlayer->surname = newPlayer->name + len1+1;
        memcpy(newPlayer->surname, surname, len2+1);
        plyer->xp = xp;
    }
    return newPlayer;
}

Team *createTeam(Player *player, char *name) {
    Team *newTeam;
    int len1;

    len1 = strlen(name);
    newTeam = malloc(sizeof(Team) + len1+1);
    if(newTeam != NULL) {
        newTeam->next = NULL;
        newTeam->name = (char *)newTeam + sizeof(Team);
        memcpy(newTeam->name, name, len1+1);
        newTeam->player = player;
    }
    return newTeam;
}
```

This also means that it's easy to free anything - e.g. you can `free(player)` without messing about with the individual fields.

Note: I got rid of `List_Node` and put a `next` field in the `Team` structure. This helps to improve performance for iteration (and also reduces excessive malloc/free). To understand this, imagine you're listing all team names and do something like this:

```
    while(node != NULL) {
        printf("name: %s\n", node->team->name)
        node = node->next;
    }
```

In this case; CPU stalls while it waits for `node` to get fetched from memory, then stalls while it waits for `node->team` to get fetched from memory. Now imagine this:

```
    while(team != NULL) {
        printf("name: %s\n", team->name)
        team = team->next;
    }
```

In this case; CPU stalls once instead of twice so it's faster to iterate through the list.

Comment: Another idea: Stall-wise, it may also help to prefetch the next item as soon as you start processing the current item. By the time you’ll need the next item, it’s likely to be fetched and in the cache. A corollary to this: iterating the list without doing useful work is going to perform worse (have more overhead and stall cycles) than iterating it while doing some work on every visited element. This may sound counterintuitive – but only if cache is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If we use this function to create an empty node:

```
void create_list_Node(List_Node *temp)
{
    temp->team = calloc(1, sizeof(Team));
    temp->team->player = calloc(1, sizeof(Player));
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

How you allocate the namn:s and surname depends on where these strings get from. If you get an allocated pointer that no other code will free, you can just "adopt" the pointer:

```
char *mystring;
... code that allocates
temp->team->name = mystring;
```

If you have a local string array, just dup it:

```
char local[100];
... code that fill it, maybe gets()
temp->team->name = strdup(local);
```

Don't forget to free strings and structures!